# I am getting two appBar in flutter app. I am trying to add Drawer widget and TabBar widget in flutter app

Tags: flutter, drawerlayout, flutter-routes

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stray_animal_emergencyrescue/signUpPage.dart';
import './commons/commonWidgets.dart';
import 'package:stray_animal_emergencyrescue/loggedIn.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //title: 'Flutter login UI',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //String showPasswordText = "Show Password";
  bool obscurePasswordText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final passwordField = TextField(
      obscureText: obscurePasswordText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Password",
          //border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                this.obscurePasswordText = !obscurePasswordText;
              });
            },
          )),
    );

    final loginButon = Material(
      //elevation: 5.0,
      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialButton(
        //minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogIn()),
          );
        },
        child: Text('Login', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );

    final facebookContinueButton = Material(
      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialButton(
        //minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
        },
        child: Text('Facebook', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );

    final googleContinueButton = Material(
      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialButton(
        //minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
        },
        child: Text('Google ', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );

    final signUpButton = Material(
      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialButton(
        //minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormScreen()),
          );
          //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
        },
        child: Text('Sign Up ', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Animal Emergency App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          //color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                //SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                getTextFieldWidget(),
                SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                passwordField,
                sizedBoxWidget,
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    facebookContinueButton,
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    googleContinueButton,
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    loginButon
                  ],
                ),
                /*loginButon,
                signUpButton,*/
                sizedBoxWidget,
                const Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 20,
                  thickness: 1,
                  indent: 20,
                  endIndent: 0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    signUpButton
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**loggedIn.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './tabbarviews/emergencyresue/EmergencyHome.dart';
import './tabbarviews/animalcruelty/animalCrueltyHome.dart';
import './tabbarviews/bloodbank/bloodBankHome.dart';

class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    EmergencyHome(),
    AnimalCrueltyHome(),
    BloodBankHome()
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First app bar appearing'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: CircleAvatar(
              //child: Text("SC"),
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/760279.jpg'),
              //backgroundImage: ,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(title: Text("Primary")),
            MyListTile(
                "Home",
                false,
                "Your customized News Feed about people you follow, ongoing rescues, nearby activities, adoptions etc.",
                3,
                Icons.home,
                true,
                () {}),
            MyListTile(
                "News & Media Coverage",
                false,
                "News about incidents which need immediate action, changing Laws",
                3,
                Icons.home,
                false,
                () {}),
            MyListTile(
                "Report",
                true,
                "Report cases with evidences anonymously",
                3,
                Icons.announcement,
                false,
                () {}),
            MyListTile(
                "Blood Bank",
                true,
                "Details to donate blood ",
                3,
                Icons.medical_services,
                false,
                () {}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pets),
            label: 'Emergency Rescue',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_alert),
            label: 'Report Cruelty',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.medical_services),
            label: 'Blood Bank',
          ),
          /*BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              label: 'Safe Hands',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue),*/
        ],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Safe Hands
class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isThreeLine;
  final String subtitle;
  final int maxLines;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool selected;
  final Function onTap;

  MyListTile(this.title, this.isThreeLine, this.subtitle, this.maxLines,
      this.icon, this.selected, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
        isThreeLine: isThreeLine,
        subtitle:
            Text(subtitle, maxLines: maxLines, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
        leading: Icon(icon),
        selected: selected,
        onTap: onTap);
  }
}
```

**EmergencyHome.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './finishedAnimalEmergencies.dart';
import './reportAnimalEmergency.dart';
import './ongoingAnimalEmergencies.dart';

class EmergencyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EmergencyHomeState createState() => _EmergencyHomeState();
}

class _EmergencyHomeState extends State<EmergencyHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second appBar appearing"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                //icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                text: "Report",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Ongoing",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Finished",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ReportAnimalEmergency(),
            OngoingAnimalEmergencies(),
            FinishedAnimalEmergencies(),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
*The issue I am facing is two appBar, I tried removing appBar from loggedIn.dart but Drawer hamburger icon is not showing, and I cannot remove appBar from emergencyHome.dart as I wont be able to add Tab bar. What is viable solution for this? Please help how to Structure by app and routes to easily manage navigation within app*

Comment: There are two appBars because you have specified two app bars. If the app bar you need is the first app bar then why is the second app bar added?

Comment: I had to add second AppBar so that I can add TabBar. Tabbar can be placed in Bottom property of AppBar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the appbar from EmergencyHome.dart
this will remove the second app title. But there will be that shadow from the first app bar so put `elvation:0`
so, this will look like one appbar now your drawer will also work.

Comment: I cannot place TabBar without AppBar. So I cant remove AppBar.

Comment: please check the below answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to make two appbar to get the drawer property. Use DefaultTabController then inside that you can use scaffold.so, you can have `drawer: Drawer()` inside that you can also get a appbar with it with TabBar as it's `bottom`.
This is most suitable for you according to your use case.

i will put the full code below so you can copy it.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
               Tab(
                  text: "report",
                ),
                Tab(text: "ongoing"),
                Tab(text: "completed"),
              ],
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: In my main.dart, I have login and signup buttons. Only after user clicks login, then user is directed to loggedIn.dart. Please check my main.dart file in question and suggest me a solution.

Comment: Yes, you can have a login page before and use on pressed function in the login button. `onPressed: () {
          //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => //here you will go to the new page   ),
          );
        },`

Comment: Does this fixed your issue

Comment: I am beginner to flutter, I fixed my issue with flexibleSpace but even I am still stuggling with navigation and routing, I need to change whole project structure. So my issue is not yet fixed.

Comment: add a question here about navigation and routing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexibleSpace in EmergencyHome.dart

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  //icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  text: "Report",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "Ongoing",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "Finished",
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
        ReportAnimalEmergency(),
        OngoingAnimalEmergencies(),
        FinishedAnimalEmergencies(),
        ],
      ),
    )
);
```